# I recently jump started my 2004 pontiac grand prix gtp that has a Pioneer model fh-x700bt stereo. It now doesn't work. what could be wrong?

Tags: pontiac, audio

My stereo wont play after jumpstarting my car.

Comment: Did you check fuses?

Answer (score 2):

My best guess would be that the surge blew the inline fuse in the wiring on the back of the stereo itself. You will need to remove the stereo and the fuse should be on the positive wire (usually a red wire). Its probably spring loaded push the ends together to turn the case and open it.